# Parsing JSON with RestKit .20

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

Did some searching and was unable to find any suitable answers.  Thanks in advance for helping me solve my probably trivial problem.

Here is the Json in question:

```
   {
   "User":{
      "UserEvents":[

      ],
      "Vendor":null,
      "UserId":7,
      "CreatedDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00",
      "UserName":"jasondboland@gmail.com",
      "LoginCount":0,
      "LastLogin":null,
      "CurrentEventId":6,
      "Company":null,
      "FirstName":"Wedding Pro",
      "LastName":"Boland",
      "Gender":"female",
      "Country":null,
      "FacebookLink":null,
      "FacebookData":null,
      "PaymentToken":"",
      "BillingAddress":null,
      "ShippingAddress":null,
      "ShipToPreference":1,
      "ReferralId":null,
      "BulkLicenseUpgrade":false,
      "DisplayName":"Wedding Pro Boland",
      "ImpersonateUser":null,
      "VendorInd":false,
      "AvailableLicenses":0
   },
   "Theme":{
      "ThemeId":2,
      "Name":"Tropical Beach 1",
      "ThumbnailImage":"~/images/themes/tropical_beach_registry_t.jpg",
      "LargeImage":"~/images/themes/tropical_beach_registry.jpg",
      "Type":1,
      "AccessLevel":1,
      "StyleName":"tropic-beach",
      "ActiveInd":true
   },
   "RegistryItems":[

   ],
   "Organizers":[
      {
         "OrganizerId":11,
         "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.687",
         "Address":null,
         "OrganizerType":1,
         "FirstName":"Jason",
         "LastName":"Boland",
         "Email":"jasondboland@gmail.com",
         "Phone":"7143922631",
         "FacebookId":null,
         "PrimaryAccountInd":true,
         "VerifiedInd":true,
         "ActiveInd":true
      },
      {
         "OrganizerId":12,
         "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.75",
         "Address":null,
         "OrganizerType":0,
         "FirstName":"Ezzy",
         "LastName":"Castillo",
         "Email":null,
         "Phone":null,
         "FacebookId":null,
         "PrimaryAccountInd":false,
         "VerifiedInd":false,
         "ActiveInd":true
      }
   ],
   "Attendees":[

   ],
   "Schedules":[
      {
         "ScheduleId":11,
         "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.763",
         "ScheduleType":2,
         "Name":"Reception",
         "Description":"Sea Cliff Country Club",
         "DateStart":"2013-06-22T16:00:00",
         "DateEnd":null,
         "Address":null,
         "ShowOnline":false,
         "ActiveInd":true
      },
      {
         "ScheduleId":12,
         "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.763",
         "ScheduleType":1,
         "Name":"Ceremony",
         "Description":"Sea Cliff Country Club",
         "DateStart":"2013-06-22T15:30:00",
         "DateEnd":null,
         "Address":null,
         "ShowOnline":false,
         "ActiveInd":true
      }
   ],
   "EventImages":[
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/aff69cb6-930b-4982-86e0-143d43a91da9_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/62b9c7e3-9ef8-41aa-b008-40847eb2eb18_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/b7281259-793d-4a7e-a2c7-466e2748a049_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/37cecb6b-0819-4a5e-aa21-475dfdad28c3_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/8f51398e-2cdf-47d2-a9bb-4fc32698ec18_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/a0e5f5c5-43f1-40db-b6cb-893bdf8d318e_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/17edaee6-8bdb-4988-847c-8977779c9000_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/0d460b63-9b65-4078-9660-a066c5390957_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/63536715-01ad-473f-b213-ba46f2f8a7d0_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      },
      {
         "ImageID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
         "Container":null,
         "ImageName":null,
         "ImageDesc":null,
         "ThumbURL":null,
         "MediumURL":null,
         "LargeURL":"https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/91f0675a-5df1-4c68-ae1f-e7db0c322e33_l",
         "ImageType":0,
         "SortOrder":0.0,
         "UserEvents":null,
         "RegistryItems":null
      }
   ],
   "UserEventId":6,
   "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.56",
   "EventType":0,
   "Name":"Jason Boland and Ezzy Castillo's Wedding",
   "Description":"We can't wait to start out our lives together with a once in a lifetime trip to the south pacific.",
   "Date":"2013-06-22T00:00:00",
   "PaymentType":1,
   "CurrencyType":1,
   "EventLevel":1,
   "RequestAddresses":true,
   "ReferralCode":null,
   "EventURL":"JasonAndEzzy",
   "PublishedInd":true,
   "PublishedDate":"2013-07-17T16:31:02.687",
   "GalleryPurchasedInd":true,
   "GalleryPurchasedDate":"2013-05-16T20:02:36.757",
   "RequirePasswordOnGallery":false,
   "EventPassword":"",
   "BudgetPurchasedInd":true,
   "BudgetPurchasedDate":"2013-05-16T20:02:36.757",
   "GuestlistPurchasedInd":true,
   "GuestlistPurchasedDate":"2013-05-16T20:02:36.757",
   "GuestListInfoRequestsSent":null,
   "GuestListInfoRequestsMessage":null,
   "SampleInd":false,
   "ActiveInd":true,
   "DaysUntilWedding":"-25.13:43:16.6650000",
   "PrimaryOrganizer":{
      "OrganizerId":11,
      "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.687",
      "Address":null,
      "OrganizerType":1,
      "FirstName":"Jason",
      "LastName":"Boland",
      "Email":"jasondboland@gmail.com",
      "Phone":"7143922631",
      "FacebookId":null,
      "PrimaryAccountInd":true,
      "VerifiedInd":true,
      "ActiveInd":true
   },
   "CeremonySchedule":{
      "ScheduleId":12,
      "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.763",
      "ScheduleType":1,
      "Name":"Ceremony",
      "Description":"Sea Cliff Country Club",
      "DateStart":"2013-06-22T15:30:00",
      "DateEnd":null,
      "Address":null,
      "ShowOnline":false,
      "ActiveInd":true
   },
   "ReceptionSchedule":{
      "ScheduleId":11,
      "CreatedDate":"2013-04-25T20:35:40.763",
      "ScheduleType":2,
      "Name":"Reception",
      "Description":"Sea Cliff Country Club",
      "DateStart":"2013-06-22T16:00:00",
      "DateEnd":null,
      "Address":null,
      "ShowOnline":false,
      "ActiveInd":true
   }
}
```

Object:

```
@interface RKImage : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *LargeURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *ImageID;
@end
```

Attempted Code:

```
RKObjectMapping* wMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKImage class]];
    [wMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     //@"ImageID": @"ImageID",
     @"LargeURL": @"LargeURL"
     }];

    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:wMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"EventImages" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.cloudapp.net/api/mobilegallery/1"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
    [objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Articles: %@", mappingResult.array);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];

    [objectRequestOperation start];
```

I'm getting the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RKImage 0xa25b240> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key LargeURL.'`

Edit:  Error with logging enabled

> 2013-07-17 16:04:43.168 SimplyTieGallery[1002:c07] I
>   restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:174 GET
>   'http://4451cfc5be9c49f4896a2dd6eeec96c9.cloudapp.net/api/mobilegallery/1'
>   2013-07-17 16:04:44.927 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] D
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:390 Executing mapping
>   operation for representation: {
>       ActiveInd = 1;
>       Attendees =     (
>       );
>       BudgetPurchasedDate = "";
>       BudgetPurchasedInd = 0;
>       CeremonySchedule =     {
>           ActiveInd = 1;
>           Address = "";
>           CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.803";
>           DateEnd = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>           DateStart = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>           Description = "Falkirk Estate and Country Club";
>           Name = Ceremony;
>           ScheduleId = 2;
>           ScheduleType = 1;
>           ShowOnline = 1;
>       };
>       CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:13.93";
>       CurrencyType = 1;
>       Date = "2013-10-08T00:00:00";
>       DaysUntilWedding = "82.00:55:14.3863200";
>       Description = "We will soon be Mr. and Ms. Jones and just can't wait! While everyone is recovering from the massive party (our
>   wedding) we will be boarding a plane to Bora Bora to start our lives
>   together in grand fashion!  We are lucky to be blessed with a fully
>   stocked home so we have decided to use SimplyTie to help us create the
>   most amazing honeymoon we could think of.  We can\U2019t thank
>   everyone enough for all your love, support and generosity!  Thank you
>   so much!  John and Judy Jones";
>       EventImages =     (
>                   {
>               Container = "";
>               ImageDesc = "";
>               ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>               ImageName = "";
>               ImageType = 0;
>               LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/c4d56b3d-840e-4093-bdc8-8369cf05da34_l";
>               MediumURL = "";
>               RegistryItems = "";
>               SortOrder = 0;
>               ThumbURL = "";
>               UserEvents = "";
>           },
>                   {
>               Container = "";
>               ImageDesc = "";
>               ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>               ImageName = "";
>               ImageType = 0;
>               LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/cd22c262-8cbc-480b-b0ee-a4b33e248b70_l";
>               MediumURL = "";
>               RegistryItems = "";
>               SortOrder = 0;
>               ThumbURL = "";
>               UserEvents = "";
>           }
>       );
>       EventLevel = 1;
>       EventPassword = "";
>       EventType = 0;
>       EventURL = BoraBoraSample;
>       GalleryPurchasedDate = "2013-04-26T00:11:45.427";
>       GalleryPurchasedInd = 1;
>       GuestListInfoRequestsMessage = "";
>       GuestListInfoRequestsSent = "";
>       GuestlistPurchasedDate = "";
>       GuestlistPurchasedInd = 0;
>       Name = "John and Judy's Wedding";
>       Organizers =     (
>                   {
>               ActiveInd = 1;
>               Address = "";
>               CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.32";
>               Email = "JudyMcGride@SimplyTie.com";
>               FacebookId = "";
>               FirstName = Judy;
>               LastName = McBride;
>               OrganizerId = 1;
>               OrganizerType = 0;
>               Phone = "";
>               PrimaryAccountInd = 1;
>               VerifiedInd = 1;
>           },
>                   {
>               ActiveInd = 1;
>               Address = "";
>               CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.323";
>               Email = "JohnJones@SimplyTie.com";
>               FacebookId = "";
>               FirstName = John;
>               LastName = Jones;
>               OrganizerId = 2;
>               OrganizerType = 1;
>               Phone = "";
>               PrimaryAccountInd = 0;
>               VerifiedInd = 1;
>           }
>       );
>       PaymentType = 1;
>       PrimaryOrganizer =     {
>           ActiveInd = 1;
>           Address = "";
>           CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.32";
>           Email = "JudyMcGride@SimplyTie.com";
>           FacebookId = "";
>           FirstName = Judy;
>           LastName = McBride;
>           OrganizerId = 1;
>           OrganizerType = 0;
>           Phone = "";
>           PrimaryAccountInd = 1;
>           VerifiedInd = 1;
>       };
>       PublishedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:13.93";
>       PublishedInd = 1;
>       ReceptionSchedule =     {
>           ActiveInd = 1;
>           Address = "";
>           CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.803";
>           DateEnd = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>           DateStart = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>           Description = "Falkirk Estate and Country Club";
>           Name = Reception;
>           ScheduleId = 1;
>           ScheduleType = 2;
>           ShowOnline = 1;
>       };
>       ReferralCode = "";
>       RegistryItems =     (
>       );
>       RequestAddresses = 1;
>       RequirePasswordOnGallery = 0;
>       SampleInd = 1;
>       Schedules =     (
>                   {
>               ActiveInd = 1;
>               Address = "";
>               CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.803";
>               DateEnd = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>               DateStart = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>               Description = "Falkirk Estate and Country Club";
>               Name = Reception;
>               ScheduleId = 1;
>               ScheduleType = 2;
>               ShowOnline = 1;
>           },
>                   {
>               ActiveInd = 1;
>               Address = "";
>               CreatedDate = "2013-04-11T13:11:16.803";
>               DateEnd = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>               DateStart = "2013-10-08T13:11:16";
>               Description = "Falkirk Estate and Country Club";
>               Name = Ceremony;
>               ScheduleId = 2;
>               ScheduleType = 1;
>               ShowOnline = 1;
>           }
>       );
>       Theme =     {
>           AccessLevel = 1;
>           ActiveInd = 1;
>           LargeImage = "~/images/themes/tropical_beach_registry.jpg";
>           Name = "Tropical Beach 1";
>           StyleName = "tropic-beach";
>           ThemeId = 2;
>           ThumbnailImage = "~/images/themes/tropical_beach_registry_t.jpg";
>           Type = 1;
>       };
>       User =     {
>           AvailableLicenses = 0;
>           BillingAddress = "";
>           BulkLicenseUpgrade = 0;
>           Company = "";
>           Country = "";
>           CreatedDate = "1900-01-01T00:00:00";
>           CurrentEventId = 1;
>           DisplayName = "John Sample";
>           FacebookData = "";
>           FacebookLink = "";
>           FirstName = John;
>           Gender = Male;
>           ImpersonateUser = "";
>           LastLogin = "";
>           LastName = Sample;
>           LoginCount = 0;
>           PaymentToken = "";
>           ReferralId = "";
>           ShipToPreference = 2;
>           ShippingAddress = "";
>           UserEvents =         (
>           );
>           UserId = 1;
>           UserName = "boraborasample@simplytie.com";
>           Vendor = "";
>           VendorInd = 0;
>       };
>       UserEventId = 1; }  and targetObject: (null) 2013-07-17 16:04:44.930 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] T
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:333 Examining keyPath
>   'EventImages' for mappable content... 2013-07-17 16:04:44.930
>   SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] D
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:310 Found mappable
>   collection at keyPath 'EventImages': (
>           {
>           Container = "";
>           ImageDesc = "";
>           ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>           ImageName = "";
>           ImageType = 0;
>           LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/c4d56b3d-840e-4093-bdc8-8369cf05da34_l";
>           MediumURL = "";
>           RegistryItems = "";
>           SortOrder = 0;
>           ThumbURL = "";
>           UserEvents = "";
>       },
>           {
>           Container = "";
>           ImageDesc = "";
>           ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>           ImageName = "";
>           ImageType = 0;
>           LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/cd22c262-8cbc-480b-b0ee-a4b33e248b70_l";
>           MediumURL = "";
>           RegistryItems = "";
>           SortOrder = 0;
>           ThumbURL = "";
>           UserEvents = "";
>       } ) 2013-07-17 16:04:44.931 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:244 Asked to map source
>   object {
>       Container = "";
>       ImageDesc = "";
>       ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>       ImageName = "";
>       ImageType = 0;
>       LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/c4d56b3d-840e-4093-bdc8-8369cf05da34_l";
>       MediumURL = "";
>       RegistryItems = "";
>       SortOrder = 0;
>       ThumbURL = "";
>       UserEvents = ""; } with mapping  LargeURL>" )> 2013-07-17 16:04:44.931 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] D
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:912 Starting mapping
>   operation... 2013-07-17 16:04:44.932 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] T
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:913 Performing mapping
>   operation:  for 'RKImage' object.
>   Mapping values from object {
>       Container = "";
>       ImageDesc = "";
>       ImageID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
>       ImageName = "";
>       ImageType = 0;
>       LargeURL = "https://jjcompanies.blob.core.windows.net/eventimages/c4d56b3d-840e-4093-bdc8-8369cf05da34_l";
>       MediumURL = "";
>       RegistryItems = "";
>       SortOrder = 0;
>       ThumbURL = "";
>       UserEvents = ""; } to object  with object mapping (null) 2013-07-17 16:04:44.932
>   SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] T
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:515 Mapping attribute
>   value keyPath 'LargeURL' to 'LargeURL' 2013-07-17 16:04:44.933
>   SimplyTieGallery[1002:1703] D
>   restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:126 Cached property
>   inspection for Class 'RKImage': {
>       ImageID =     {
>           isPrimitive = 0;
>           keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
>           name = ImageID;
>       };
>       LargeURL =     {
>           isPrimitive = 0;
>           keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
>           name = LargeURL;
>       }; } 2013-07-17 16:04:44.933 SimplyTieGallery[1002:4103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key LargeURL.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1e68012 0x1c8de7e 0x1ef0fb1 0x1962d1d 0x18cf00b 0x18cefbd 0x18ed247 0xa3561 0xa4a92 0xa5e39 0xad45d
>   0x18ef453 0x18ef164 0x9bb79 0x9b018 0x1e61e7c 0x1e61a16 0x1e61925
>   0x9accb 0x9cbff 0x9d657 0x9e021 0x18ef453 0x18ef164 0x8c850 0x8a955
>   0x18ef453 0x18ef164 0x197ba31 0x254b53f 0x255d014 0x254e2e8 0x254e450
>   0x91453e72 0x9143bd2a) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an
>   exception (lldb)

Tried messing with keyPaths and I'm just getting nowhere fast.  Thanks!

Comment: Please format the JSON so its readable and you can see the structure (indentation).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the keypath should be @"User.EventImages". Is the error a copy and paste in your question?

Comment: Wain, the error is a copy paste, and i think the first indent is just a copy/paste/format error.  User should be on the same level as EventImages.  Just to make sure, I now get the following error:Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched." UserInfo=0xa573780 {DetailedErrors=(
), NSLocalizedFailureReason=The mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations at the key paths searched: User.EventImages

Comment: Ok, careful scrolling later, yes. What other code is in the `RKImage` class? Did you try cleaning the project? Nothing is obviously wrong...

Comment: Nothing else is in the class other than #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Comment: Clean, rebuild, re-run, same error (original one)

Comment: Is the .m included in the target? Turn on trace logging: `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: The .M is included in the target (it wouldnt compile if not right?)  Anyhow, I edited the original question with the results now that trace logging is enabled.  Thanks!

Comment: Change the name to follow coding standards ("largeURL").

Comment: Did the name change help? Your current name isn't KVC compliant so when RestKit tries to read the current value it looks to be failing.

Comment: Wain, turns out I had @dynamic LargeURL in the .M file for RKImage.  Removing those solved the problem.  They were in some other example I ran across but must have been incompatible.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dynamic would mean that the accessor methods aren't added (similar to the effect of not having the .m file in the target).